# Hibernate Search. Exclusion from indexing records with specific properties

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have two entites, Book:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book extends BaseEntity {
@Field
@Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
private String subtitle;
private boolean prohibited;

@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.DAY)
private Date publicationDate;

@IndexedEmbedded
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(value = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();

public Book() {
}
```

and Author

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = EnglishAnalyzer.class)
public class Author extends Identifiable<Long> {
@Field
private String name;
```

I must find only that the author whose book is not prohibited. If I invoke that query

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(c).get();
    Query luceneQuery = qb
            .keyword()
            .fuzzy()
            .onFields("name")
            .matching(q)
            .createQuery();

    FullTextQuery createFullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Author.class);
```

The question is, how can I understand what the author of the book is prohibited? Maybe something like a query, you can add a condition to the search was only in those books that are not banned? Or how to do something so that luсene not index forbidden books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by implementing `EntityIndexingInterceptor` and then define the implentation in your domain class as:

```
@Indexed(interceptor=BookIndexingInterceptor.class)
public class Book extends BaseEntity{
```

Example of implementation is as below:

```
   public class BookIndexingInterceptor implements
        EntityIndexingInterceptor<Book> {
    @Override
    public IndexingOverride onAdd(Book entity) {
        if(entity.prohibited == true)
            return IndexingOverride.SKIP;

        return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public IndexingOverride onUpdate(Book entity) {
        if(entity.prohibited == true)
            return IndexingOverride.REMOVE;

        return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public IndexingOverride onDelete(Book entity) {
        return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public IndexingOverride onCollectionUpdate(Book entity) {
        if(entity.prohibited == true)
            return IndexingOverride.REMOVE;

        return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I will implement this interceptor Authors will not removed from lucene index, and they would be found

Comment: Indexing of Book as well as `@IndexedEmbedded` entity will skip for prohibited.

Author entitiy if indexed seperatly then it will be no effect while indexing Book entity.

Comment: But if the book originally was not banned, it will index and index all of its authors, and then we will do the forbidden book it will be skipped, and its list of authors is removed from the index or not?

Comment: did not get you ... here u are saying that trying to make the book banned after they are indexed which was previously NOT banned ??

Comment: Then you can try `IndexingOverride.REMOVE;` in the call of `onUpdate` method.

I have also updated my answer.....